Linux mint doesn't work while using grub2win
I got a Asus vevobook resently and the laptop is very slow so I try to switch my os to linux mint cinnamon v21.3 by burning my sd card and booting it. Later I disable both safeboot and fastboot but since the sd card (showing, ignored EFI media in grub partlist) doesn't show up I use grub2win.
While I try to run linux mint this error keep showing on
`GNU Grub is preparing to boot Mint Linux
error: ../../grub-core/fs/fshelp.c:257:file '/vmlinuz' not found.
error: ../../grub-core/loader/1386/efi/linux.c: 168:you need to load the kernel first. error: ../../grub-core/commands/boot.c:196: you need to load the kernel first.
Press and release the ESC key quickly to skip the countdown
Hold down the SHIFT key two seconds to pause for more options
Countdown to load o
Press any key to continue.....`.
I check many doubt questions and also multiple youtube videos but no growth.
Funny thing is I changing OS for 3 days straight(Windows 11).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Most laptops can't boot from (external) SD cards. Use a USB stick like everybody else to boot the live session and then install normally in the internal drive. An USB adapter for the SD or microSD card also works.

I used usb stick and now it's working but it would be worth if I try it in sd card.
